# Terminal window automatically resizes, overlapping with Launcher

Tags: launcher, gnome-terminal, 22.04, resize, maximized

I run an out-of-the-box **Ubuntu 22.04** installation on a relatively small X1 Thinkpad with a 13 inch display. The **Gnome Launcher** is on the left hand side of the screen and I run my **Terminal** window full-screen. When I click the full-screen button on the top right, it maximizes perfectly, but leaving the necessary space for the Launcher. Most often, I have several tabs open, and often one or more of them host a `tmux` session. So far, all is fine.

After some time, but only when I don't look at the screen and then return to it, I frequently discover that *my Terminal window has expanded horizontally*, now overlapping with the Launcher buttons. Unzooming and re-maximizing fixes the issue for now, but only until I look away again.

What causes this strange behavior and how can I mitigate it?

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same annoying behavior. Although I found a way to improve the use-experience and minimize the interference by selecting "Auto-hide the Doc" in settings -> Appearance option. This way, my docker isn't seen by default and I get much wider terminal space to operate with. Hopefully it helps!